# Indexing dynamic vector of class probabilities

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, probability

For my code, I have a large (up to 40,000) vector of class probabilities. This set of class probabilities also needs to be reweighted regularly, so assume it will change on every call of the code. The vector sums to 1. I need to efficiently search through this for the index corresponding to that probability.

As an example - say the vector was `[0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]`, uniform prob across 4 objects. My probability result is a 0.67. This corresponds to index 3, since `0.67 > sum(probvec[0:1])` but `0.67 <= sum(probvec[0:2])`.

I'm open to changing the probability vector to make it the running sum, i.e. `[0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]`, though then I'd also need a suggestion as to how to perform updates.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm leaning towards storing the cumulative sums, which you can update a little more efficiently by only updating sums k through n when item k changes (by adding the change in item k to every item thereafter). You don't really need to normalize the cumulative sums since instead you can generate a random number in (0, final sum) instead of (0, 1) and then do a binary search as suggested by horcrux.

Answer (score 0):

- **Step 1**: pre-compute all the partial sums up to the `i`-th index.
- **Step 2**: scan your `sums_probvec` with binary search for obtaining the result in logtime.

```py
import numpy as np

probvec = np.full(4, 0.25)
prob = 0.67

# pre-compute all the partial sums up to the i-th index
sum_probvec = [probvec[0]]
for i in range(1, len(probvec)) :
    sum_probvec.append(sum_probvec[i-1] + probvec[i])

# use binary search for logtime results
i = 0
j = len(sum_probvec)
while i != j-1:
    mid = (i + j) // 2
    if prob > sum_probvec[mid]:
        i = mid
    else:
        j = mid
index = i+2

print (index) # 3
```